# China - 72 Hours Visa on Arrival rule

Tags: china, us-citizens, visas-on-arrival, transit-visas

I am US citizen traveling to Hong Kong via Beijing. Below are my flights details

Landing in Beijing Friday, 2 October 2015, 08:50:31
Departure to HK Monday, 5 October 2015, 12:00:00

So my total duration is 3 days, 3 hours, 9 minutes and 29 seconds

If I count total number of hours based on the flight times I am over 3 hours 10 minutes. I would like to know if I will run into any issues at the airport? Based on the Wiki posted on the [FlyerTalk](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/china/708095-china-24-hour-72-hour-transit-without-visa-twov-rules-master-thread-76.html#post25473597) I should be fine as the 72 hours count begins at the following day. Can anyone please share their experience?